# What are common statistical techniques applied to Game Theory?

Tags: game-theory

I have been examining stochastic Bayesian games as a framework for modeling multi-agent games. As this looks like an active area of research, I was wondering if any particular techniques have emerged as viable methods for system analysis of these games? A worked example would be greatly appreciated.